# Ajax in Firefox add on panel content JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i use Firefox Add on `SDK` . i have button in toolbar and in On Click Event I Show the panel html file . now i need to use ajax function in On click of html button i used in panel html file.

---

```
    <html>
    <script>
    function test()
    {
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    //some ajax Code 
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick='test()'>click Here</button>
    </html>
```

i am new in using Firefox `SDK`. Is It possible at all ?? and if it is possible then how should i do this ?

Comment: I'm hoping someone helps you out, Im not familiar with SDK so i dont know how to do it, otherwise i would help you out. But heres the documentation for sdk:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request

Comment: i hope ... thanks for help so much ... request is working fine but in main.js i have to use ajax request in panel content script :(

Comment: It looks like no one is showing up, i think this is because your question is very basic, that page i linked does all the work. Basically you set up a pageworker and your contentScript tells your pageWorker to do request then you send that back to your contentScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend . you help me a lot with this basic information you said ;) thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure man I hope you were able to figure it out, excuse the no sdk repliers.

Comment: i write content script inside of main.js and with some help of jquery lib it worked perfectly but i still don't understand why my script doesn't worked in contentscript file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use inline scripting inside a html page in a Firefox addon, add the script as a packaged local resource and it will be executed.

Basically you have to split in two, the HTML and the JS and reference the JS in the HTML